# Administrate Gem does not yet support namespaced models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-administrate

Am working on a Modular Rails Application by following TutsPlus Modular Rails App training [here](https://github.com/mmuehlberger/tutsplus-modular-rails-app).

However, after install *Administrate Gem* and running `rails generate administrate:install` to install my dashboard, I get the error as is in the image below:

[image]

In short Administrated Gem doesn't work with a Modular Rails App. How do I solve this problem or how do I make Administrate Gem support Namespaced Models???

**What I have done:**

I have tried to hard code a dashboard, but wont just work with Administrate (Rails just cant fine Administrate Gem in a Modular Rails App because of that error, but works with a Monolithic Rails App).

Answer (score 1):

after merging this [PR](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/pull/871), Now Administrate supports the namespace resources.
An example solution for the namespaced models is below. Let's suppose you have a post model in the blog namespace.

**Model**

```
app/models/blog/post.rb
```

Now you want to add it to the admin dashboard.
just follow this structure to make it work.

**config/routes.rb**

```
namespace :admin do
    namespace :blog do
      resources :posts
    end
    root to: "admin_users#index"
end
```

**#app/admin/blog/posts_controller.rb**

```
module Admin
  class Blog::PostsController < Admin::ApplicationController
  end
end
```

**#app/dashboards/blog/posts_dashboard.rb**

```
require "administrate/base_dashboard"

class Blog::PostDashboard < Administrate::BaseDashboard
  #normal stuff
end
```

For a detailed solution please check this [discussion](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/issues/179)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to figure out how to add a single-table inheritance (STI) model to your Administrate dashboard, here is how I was able to accomplish this using version `0.18.0` of the Administrate gem:

1. Use the gem's generator to scaffold out a new controller and dashboard object for the **base class** of your model:

```bash
 rails generate administrate:dashboard Foo::Base
```

2. Add a namespaced route definition to your `routes.rb` file:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
    namespace :admin do
      ...
      namespace :foo do
        resources :bases
      end
      ...
    end
```

3. Move the newly-generated controller to a subfolder with the name of your models namespace. For example, `controllers > admin > bases_controller.rb` becomes `controllers > admin > foo > bases_controller.rb`
4. Update the controller by overriding the `find_resource(param)` method. Note the use of [`becomes`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/becomes) This is necessary because without it, the Administrate gem will try to generate paths based on the specific model instances class (like `Foo::Bar`), but above in the `routes.rb` file, we've only added routes for the `Foo::Base` class.

```rb
module Admin
  class Foo::BasesController < Admin::ApplicationController

    ...

    def find_resource(param)
      resource_class.find_by!(id: param)
        .becomes(resource_class) # this ensures that the resource is presented as an Foo::Base,
                                  # not as an Foo::Bar, Foo::Baz, etc.
    end
```

5. Finally, you'll need to add a custom inflector to handle the pluralization of the word `Base`. Without it, for some reason, Rails pluralizes `Base` to `Basis` instead of `Bases` (the latter of which Administrate expects). Without this, you'll see error messages like:

```bash
NameError (uninitialized constant Foo::BasisDashboard):
```

That's it!

I should make a PR to update the generator's behaviour to do this automatically for STI models, but in the meanwhile, these work-arounds got my namespaced model added to a dashboard.

Answer (score -2):

Read and follow carefully the instruction, then update me

> ## [What Is Administrate?](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate#getting-started)
>
> Administrate is a library for Rails apps that automatically generates admin dashboards. Administrate's admin dashboards give non-technical users clean interfaces that allow them to create, edit, search, and delete records for any model in the application.
>
> Administrate solves the same problem as Rails Admin and ActiveAdmin, but aims to provide a better user experience for site admins, and to be easier for developers to customize.
>
> To accomplish these goals, Administrate follows a few guiding principles:

- No DSLs (domain-specific languages)
- Support the simplest use cases,
  and let the user override defaults with standard tools such as plain
  Rails controllers and views.
- Break up the library into core components and plugins, so each component stays small and easy to maintain.

> ## [Getting Started](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate#getting-started)
>
> Administrate supports Rails from 4.2, up to 5.0 and beyond.
>
> Add Administrate to your Gemfile and re-bundle:

```
gem "administrate"
```

Then **RUN `bundle install`** in your terminal!!!

> The included installer will create dashboards for each model in your app, complete with routes:

```
$ rails generate administrate:install
```

> Restart your server, and visit http://localhost:3000/admin to see your new dashboard in action.
>
> For more detailed instructions or to make it work with Rails API-only applications, please go through the 'Getting Started` guide.

Comment: Its not the first time am using Administrate Gem. Unfortunately, I see it work well for a Monolithic app rather than Modular App. On a normal day, it does as you posted but not for a Modular App. Am having Administrate gem namespace error. Its clearly stated in my question.

Comment: @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi what the installer does is generating a controller right? It fails because you need to set that controller with namespace `admin::ApplicationController` inside `app/controllers/admin`, this is how their controller looks like https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/blob/master/app/controllers/administrate/application_controller.rb

Comment: Its not working. really. Better still let me ask: In a case of a Modular App, where do I install my Administrate (In the parent directory or the engine)?

Comment: @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi actually the error is about namespaced models not controllers. So probably you should check something about models too... I don't know.. you need to do some research deep in what need to be done to set your app .. .do you have gem alternatives?

Comment: Will use alternative. Can be wasting time on this. Its clear as the Warning sounds the Administrate dont support namespace.

Answer (score -3):

It supports namespace:

```
rails generate administrate:install --namespace=super_admin
```

To create Dashboard with namespace:

```
rails generate administrate:dashboard Model --namespace=super_admin
```

Comment: the dashboard itself isn't to be namespaced, the questioner wants to have a dashboard for an existing namespaced model in their app